# Hotkey for eclipse quick fix tooltip

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse gives tool tips for errors and warnings in your code. Like most tooltips, these take a few seconds to popup.

However, I've found myself fairly frustrated by the speed it takes for them to show up and am wondering if anyone knows if there's a hot key to get them to pop up quickly. Or a suggestion on how to get the auto fixes to show up quicker in general would be great.

I often refactor large pieces of my code and could really use the auto fixers if they were faster.

Answer (score 2):

F2 works for me, but the cursor has to be in the code object, or it has to be highlighted (i.e. it doesn't work while hovering).

Still, a click and a keystroke seems faster to me than waiting for the tooltip to appear.